# How can I make a new buffered reader object that starts reading from where another stopped?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, bufferedinputstream

I have a buffered reader that reads a large file line-by-line to remove duplicate lines.

Instead of loading the whole file in the memory I'd like to do this by using two buffered readers: The first iterates over fixed portions of the file, loading each portion one by one into memory.

In each iteration, the second buffered reader would from where the first one stops to the end of the file to check that the loaded portion doesn't exist anymore in the file.

The problem is that I can't make new independent buffered reader object (not reference) to start in the position the first one stopped.

I need a way to find out the first buffered reader's file position so I can tell the second buffered reader where to begin.

What I've tried so far:

Sending the first object to the second's constructor.

This actually worked, but both had the same iterator, so the first one moved with the second one to the end of the file

```
BufferedReader cleanfilereader2 = new BufferedReader(cleanfilereader);
```

`bufferedReader.mark()` sets the position of the buffered reader but I still need to know the position of the first one.

Notes:

- The number of lines is not constant
- Can't load the whole file in the memory
- Both time and memory are issues

Comment: Have you tried splitting the file into parts before reading?

Comment: i don't want to get into this , i guess this would be much easier.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is large and time is an issue, this *may* not be an optimal way, because you have to read every line very often (O(n^2) times).

*If* you have enough memory for that, I would suggest to read the file line by line and store the hash value of each line in an ArrayList. This only needs 4 bytes (one integer) for every line. Then you can search for duplicates in this array list (fast, as it is in memory). This gives you a list of all potential duplicates, and you only have to check whether these are real duplicates while you remove them.

Comment: Nice solution! Though it would be better to track the hashes in a map, keyed on hash with value of the duplicate line number. That way when he iterates the file again for writing he can skip lines with a particular hash if their line number matches the stored value.

Comment: for sure i've thought of that ,, i've implemented that and i faced java heap problems , i could increase the heap size but i'm intending to write something that works with large files around 4 and 5 GB so this won't be applicable

Comment: Then thumbs up for actually trying it out. There are sadly too many programers out there who wouldn't even consider multiple approaches to that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need `BufferedReader.skip` but there is not C like `tell` to give a current position. Hence drop BufferedReader, and use a simple random access file, or java.nio, a memory mapped file buffer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to read the current position, you can use a [FileChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) as

> A file channel has a current position within its file which can be
>   both queried and modified

You can create an `InputStream` from the channel using [Channels.newInputStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Channels.html#newInputStream%28java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel%29) (without closing it if you don't want to close the underlying channel)
.

Answer (score 0):

try this... (if i'm get you correctly. )

```
import java.io.*;
class delete{
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{
FileInputStream fis1=new FileInputStream("delete.java");
FileInputStream fis2=fis1;
String temp="";
byte buff[]=new byte[100];
while(true){
if (fis1.read(buff)==-1)break;
temp=new String(buff);
System.out.print(temp);
if(fis2.read(buff)==-1)break;
temp=new String(buff);
System.out.print(temp);
}}
}
```

Output:
the above code.

The Question is really interesting. so pls comment for discussion.